# C++でのバイナリ比較

Tags: c++

Char型のポインタに文字列を格納したときに、その文字コードが自分の予測する文字コードかどうか確認する方法がわからないので教えてください。

例えば、Char *cpのcp[0]に、88という文字コードが、入っていると予測する場合は、どのように88という文字コードが入っているか確認すればいいでしょうか？（出来れば、Boostを使わない方法を教えていただければ幸いです。）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[std::char_traits](http://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/string/char_traits.html)の`to_int_type()`を使って

```
Char* cp;
if (std::char_traits<Char>::to_int_type(cp[0]) == 88) {
    ;
} else {
    ;
}
```

ということでしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
88ではなく、0x88にしたら出来ました！

Comment: 0x88とすることで期待した結果になったというのであれば、`std::char_traits<Char>::to_int_type(cp[0]) == 0x88`のほか、`cp[0] == '\x88'`としてもうまくいくと思います。

Comment: @Egtra さん、`'\x88'`はchar型でしかなく、Char型と値が一致するという保証はないような？

Comment: @Egtra さん、@sayuri さん返事遅くなってすいません。試してみたところ、`\x88`だと`error: conversion from ‘char’ to non-scalar type~`と出てダメでした。

Comment: @sayuri さん、@jpsuper さん、すみません、`Char`だったんですね。`char`と勘違いしていました。